# How do you store/share online your personal documents?

Tags: sharing, documents, storage

For photos, I use Flickr. But for other documents...Which web based online application (hosted or to install on your personal web site) do you use for PDF or word files ? If there is a user management it would be also great (for example you decide that some persons, or everyone, can see some of your documents...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Docs?
It is capable of storing PDFs but your word documents will be converted to the the google doc format. (which then can be converted back to Word or RTF or PDF etc'

Comment: I've just tried to upload one of my PDF files, Google tells me it is not a valid one. Not very convincing for a start.

Comment: Right, the PDF was really not a valid one ! Google is really a good solution indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [DropBox](http://www.getdropbox.com/), but it doesn't have access control. [drop.io](http://drop.io/) has password protection, though, so that could be used for access control.

Answer (score 1):

I use a subversion repository. I can browse it on the web if I need to, though I usually use TortoiseSVN to access it on windows machines. It's password protected, and it even has version control! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use :

- [drop.io](http://www.drop.io)
- [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Google Docs is that it changes the format of uploaded docs in its own format, with catastrophic consequences (page layout, links, summaries...). What I would like is to keep my original documents as is , if I want to .

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have created a small TrueCrypt container, zipped up my documents, added them to the TrueCrypt container and then e-mailed them to my GMail account.

Fiddly but effective. You can setup an Ant script on your desktop to create/update the zip and copy to the TrueCrypt folder and then perform the e-mail.

I have also used and am using DropBox for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SkyDrive](http://skydrive.live.com/) from Microsoft Live; plenty of space and easy access and I can use my Hotmail login (no need to remember a seperate username/password combo).